# Dynamics CRM Dynamically getting HTML webresource parent control

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

We have an embedded HTML web resource on a form with the name property of the control("WebResource_MyWebResource").

Is there a method we can use from within the HTML web resource that allows us to dynamically get the name property of it's own parent control, or will we need to pass in the webresource control name as a data parameter to use it within the script via `parent.Xrm.Page.getControl(arg)`?

We don't want to hard code the resource name as it's for generic functionality and won't necessarily know the name the end user will give to the control.

Comment: Check `window.name`, might be what you're after.

Comment: @Alex I've just tried an alert to see what it prints but it just returns a blank alert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had always wanted an easy way to get this myself and finally put the time in a while back to figure it out:

```
var win = document.defaultView || document.parentWindow; /* parentWindow for IE8- */
var parentIframeId = win.frameElement.id;
```

The above code when executed from your web resource will get you id of the iframe element which contains the web resource.

Comment: Looks good, seems to do the trick, thanks. Before i mark as the answer, is this method supported within Dynamics? As it's a bit of grey area since it's kind of a cross over from web resource script(where it would be supported) to Xrm page script where 'document.xyz'(wouldn't be supported). I was hoping there would be a 'parent.Xrm' function to achieve this but doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Yes, it's supported because you're not modifying or relying on the structure of the CRM DOM (which is not guaranteed to stay the same).